# multiprocessing.Manager().dict() can't update second level value

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

i have a dict x ,format like: x_dic = {0:{'length':2,'current':0}},but when i use Manager().dict() to pass x_dic to child process, i found the value in 'current' can't update by child process.

```
method 1: 
dic[i]['current'] += 1

method 2:
current_val = dic[i]['current']
current_val += 1
dic[i]['current'] = current_val
```

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # set config of logger
    print("{}:{}:{}".format(time.localtime().tm_hour, 
          time.localtime().tm_min, time.localtime().tm_sec))
    print(os.getpid())

    # set parameter
    lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2, initializer=start_process)

    # set test dic 
    testdic = multiprocessing.Manager().dict()
    x = {0:{'length':2,'current':0}}
    testdic.update(x)

    # before multi
    print('now value testdic',dict(testdic))

    # running
    partialmulti = partial(multi_core, testdic=testdic)
    for i, _ in enumerate(pool.imap_unordered(partialmulti,[0,0,0])):
        print('finish process: ',i)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    # after multiprocessing
    print('after multi',dict(testdic))

    pool.terminate()
```

Comment: def multi_core(i,testdic):
    # method 1
    # testdic[i]['current'] += 1

    # method 2
    current_val = testdic[i]['current']
    current_val += 1
    testdic[i]['current'] = current_val

Comment: a little hard to edit code format. Above is the multi_core function calls by the main function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when pass a python dict to Manager().dict(), python dict as the second level won't be changed. The solution is to pass anther Manager().dict() as the second level. For example:

```
valuedic = multiprocessing.Manager().dict()
valuedic.update({'length':0,'current':1})

x = {0:valuedic}
testdic.update(x)
```

then the valuedic will be successfully changed after multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with multiprocessing.Process()

```
import multiprocessing as mp

m=mp.Manager()
x_dict=m.dict({0:{'length':2,'current':0}})

procs=[]
no_of_processes=2
for i in range(no_of_processes):
    p=mp.Process(target=func_name, args=(x_dict,)) #func_name takes one argument as x_dict and does all the manupulations as required
    p.start()
    procs.append(p)  #Just creating a pointer to the current process and storing in a list

for proc in procs:
    proc.join()

print(x_dict)
```

Comment: yeah, i also saw this solution before. I am just curious why Manager.dict() can't handle this issue and this make me worry about whether other objects still have such issues. i am afraid of these unknown things

Comment: No its not the problem with Manager.dict(). It's the problem with Pool() functionsalities. Though I am not entirely sure why Pool() can't handle the Manager objects, but once I got the same problem while working with global variables in multiprocessing. So I am just suggesting a theory which is, may be while passing the dict to the function, pool makes it kond of global variable. Hence it is not on shared variable anymore. So while printing in main function, we get the global variable which has never been changed. Well that's just a guess. But yeah I guess so Process() is more implementable.